# Vertica_python and Sqlalchemy Insert

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, vertica-python

I am using sqlalchemy and vertica_python to pull down tables into python and would like to writ tables to my own schema there after but am getting an error on the df.to_sql()
I can read tables with the connection string.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('vertica+vertica_python://username:password@localhost:3306/db_name')
connection  = engine.raw_connection()

df.to_sql("df", if_exists="replace", con=connection, schema="schema_name")
```

> --> 739     raise ValueError(f'Invalid SQL: {operation}'
> 740         "\nHINT: When argument 'parameters' is a tuple/list, "
> 741         'variables in SQL should be specified with positional format (%s) placeholders. '
> 742         'Question mark (?) placeholders have to be used with use_prepared_statements=True setting.')
> 743 tlist = []
>
> ValueError: Invalid SQL:
> SELECT
> name
> FROM
> sqlite_master
> WHERE
> type IN ('table', 'view')
> AND name=?;
> HINT: When argument 'parameters' is a tuple/list, variables in SQL should be specified with positional format (%s) placeholders.
> Question mark (?) placeholders have to be used with
> use_prepared_statements=True setting.
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: The dataframe schema and the table schema have to match both both with names and with datatypes. 99% of the time if you have an issue using df.to_sql and the connection string is correct you want to ensure the column names of your dataframe at that time actually match.

Comment: for Oracle and the like it creates a new table, no? with Vertica, this is an insert statement?